# Automate creation of Notification Service Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, shell

Is there a way I can automate the creation of Notification Service 
Extension.

I want to write a script or any automation process which will create a Notification Service Extension.

1. Replace a file with the one I have written
2. Add framework to both the application

How should I go about it ? From where should I start

Comment: check if this helps: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1407184/create-notification-service-extension-from-post-bu.html